Could not find py4J jar at
I am trying to run my PMML pre-trained model in Python 3.9, but no matter what I do I have this error Could Not find py4j jar at.
None of the solutions provided on the blogs are working. And, even if I add the file manually I don't know how to make the system locate it.
I tried the solutions here but I don't even have the same files as him.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
